# Trimming /null values from string after converting from char[] (in C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, casting, char

There is an array of characters e.g.

```
char [] biggerText = new char [8];
```

then I input some values likewise:

```
biggerText[0] = (char) 12;
biggerText[1] = (char) 48;
```

then I use the following operation:

```
string smallerText= string.Join("", biggerText);
```

and when you perform `smallerText.Length` you get **8 and NOT 2**.

What is the most effective method to trim this array to omit the null values when converting to string?

Comment: did you tried some answer? Did they work? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a `List<char>`? This way, you don't have to worry about indexes, and you don't have to know the final length at the beginning (as pointed out in the comment by @n8wrl).

```
var list = new List<char>();

list.Add((char)12);
list.Add((char)48);
```

Then you can get the final `string` in a more elegant way:

```
var smallerText = new string(list.ToArray());
```

And this `string` will have the correct `Length`.

Comment: AND you don't have to declare the size up-front! A huge help in two years when your code changes and you're working with 9 chars (or more!)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new string from the array and trim the null chars from the end:

```
string smallerText = new String(biggerText).TrimEnd('\0');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
string smallerText = string.Join("", biggerText.Where(n => n != '\0'));
```

This is a good way to do it, because `Trim` will work just with white spaces and may not work well for you.

Comment: "`Trim` will work just with white spaces" - not so. You should review the documentation for `Trim`.

Comment: I did.

Removes all leading and trailing **white-space** characters from the current String object.

Comment: There is also the [String.Trim Method (Char())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which takes an array of user-defined characters to trim. Strangely, there is no documentation which says that you can supply it with a char instead an array of char, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TakeWhile` to only take the characters until you see a "null" character assuming you don't want any of the characters that might exist after the first "null" character.

```
string smallerText= string.Join("", biggerText.TakeWhile(c => c != '\0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char [] biggerText = new char [8];

    biggerText[0] = (char)12;
    biggerText[1] = (char)48;

    string smallerText= new string(biggerText).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
    int length = smallerText.Length;
```

\0 can be at any location, so just replace it with empty value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the most efficient:

```
string smallerText = new string(biggerText, 0, 2);
```

but "the most effective method to trim" is the `.Trim` method

```
string smallerText = new string(biggerText).TrimEnd(char.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with spans!

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> chars = biggerText;
string smallerText = chars.TrimEnd(char.MinValue).ToString();
```

In my opinion, this is much better than other answers. It wraps char array as `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and trim it's end by calculating actual length.

Note that it's working better with arrays, not strings. For strings, use `string.TrimEnd(char);`